# How improve servers balancing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, server, teamcity

We have an application on asp.net MVC deployed on two servers with balancing, and connected to the same base. When we building through TeamCity, they are alternately updated. The problem is that they both have to be disabled if there are scripts to measure the base. 
The question is how can database balancing be done so that scripts can be rolled in without interrupting interaction with the application?

Comment: What kind of database update do you want to perform? Why do you think this is possible in all situations?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I want to run simple SQL scripts on MS SQL DB. if you make the execution of the script after the rebuild the first server, the second which now takes all the load will stop working, and the first still does not turn on until the scripts are not fulfilled. What are the ways to roll scripts without stopping the server?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/update-database-schema-without-downtime/)

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, thanks.